# Azimuthal angle in spherical coordinates of points on $\hat z$ axis

Tags: coordinate-systems

What is the azimuthal angle $\phi$ (value or else) of a point sitting on the $\hat z$ axis? (Isn't it the angle between positive $\hat x$ axis and the projection of the radius (position vector) on the X-Y plane?)

N.B: by definition of the azimuthal angle I see that $\phi$ is ill or badly defined for points on $\hat z$ axis?! So there is not a one to one correspondance(mapping)  between catesian and spherical coordinates?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not Strictly Related : [Unit vectors in the cylindrical coordinate system as functions of position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422163/unit-vectors-in-the-cylindrical-coordinate-system-as-functions-of-position).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ are defined by $$\mathbf{x}(r,\theta,\phi)=(r\cos\phi\sin\theta,r\sin\phi\sin\theta,r\cos\theta),$$

but it is important to understand that they do not cover the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ because points must be in one-to-one correspondence with coordinates. Let me give as an example a much simpler situation. Consider $r=0$. This sets $\mathbf{x}(r,\theta,\phi)=(0,0,0)$ *regardless* of the values of $(\theta,\phi)$. So we have a whole continuum of coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ mapping to the same point. For this reason we restrict the coordinates to $r>0$.

Your issue with the $z$ axis is of the same nature. The $z$ axis is defined by $\theta=0,\pi$, since this is how we get $x=y=0$. But now observe that gives $$\mathbf{x}(r,0,\phi)=(0,0,r),\quad \mathbf{x}(r,\pi,\phi)=(0,0,-r).$$

This means that for all values of $\phi$ we get the same point on the $z$ axis. Again, the one-to-one correspondence between points and coordinates is broken here. So in the same way as we restrict $r>0$ we also restrict $0 < \theta < \pi$ with strict inequalities.

Comment: But with these restrictions on r  and thêta, how would de represent the origin O(x=0, y=0, z=0) and points on the z axis? (In physics de take generally thêta from 0 to Pi the Co-Latitude)?

Comment: In Physics we often just say that the origin is $r=0$ and the $z$ axis is $\theta=0$ for example, and take care to remember that in the first case $(\theta,\phi)$ are not well-defined there and in the second case $\phi$ is not well-defined there. In more rigorous Math we just say that the coordinate system under consideration cannot describe these points of the manifold and that if you want to deal with them you will need another set of coordinates which is able to well-represent them. In fact, in rigorous Math most of the time a single chart is insuficient to describe a whole manifold.