# How to expand the existing basis set so that it becomes more complete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, computational-physics, software

This Mathematica.SE question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284679/ is physical too, so I have decided to duplicate it here.

I have a set of anisotropic gaussian basis set which describes the ground state of the system with great accuracy.

The Hamiltonian of the system has the following form: $$H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{2}\rho^2-1$$ where $r=(\rho,z,\phi)$ is a coordinate in the cylindrical system

The anisotropic gaussian basis set which I use to solve this task:$$\psi_j=e^{-b_{0j}\;z^2}e^{-a_{0j}\;\rho^2}$$where $a_{0j}$ and $b_{0j}$ are parameters

$a_{0j}$=0.500074, 0.502676, 0.510451, 0.507502, 0.52768, 0.625164, 0.935248,
1.826161, 3.845598, 8.293859, 18.014295, 39.20736, 85.3836,
185.975252, 405.095196, 882.399269, 1922.095421, 4186.829292,
9120.018288

$b_{0j}$=0.026284, 0.057253, 0.124713, 0.184064, 0.271658, 0.429143, 0.799226,
1.740925, 3.792194, 8.2604, 17.993331, 39.194226, 85.375371,
185.970096, 405.091965, 882.397245, 1922.094153, 4186.828497,
9120.01779

The exact value of the ground state energy from the literature is -1.0222124 and this basis set with great accuracy give this value (-1.02221). It's know the excited levels energies from the literature too: -0.174, -0.069, -0.036865, -0.022815, -0.015495.
The basis set that I used give the follow values for the excited levels energies: -0.173374, -0.0199577, 0.312572, 1.18162... If the first excited level differs in the third decimal place, then the energies of the subsequent excited levels are completely different. This is because the basis set I am using is not complete and it is necessary to increase the number of basis functions in order to get more accurate values for the excited levels.

Is it possible, having a certain set of basic functions (in my case, it is 19 functions), to supplement it with additional functions so that it becomes more complete? How to do it? Because I would like to get the energies of the excited levels too.

The code in Wolfram Mathematica (in the code I rename $\rho\equiv r$):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*the basis set*)
b00 = {0.026284, 0.057253, 0.124713, 0.184064, 0.271658, 0.429143, 
   0.799226, 1.740925, 3.792194, 8.2604, 17.993331, 39.194226, 
   85.375371, 185.970096, 405.091965, 882.397245, 1922.094153, 
   4186.828497, 9120.01779};
a00 = {0.500074, 0.502676, 0.510451, 0.507502, 0.52768, 0.625164, 
   0.935248, 1.826161, 3.845598, 8.293859, 18.014295, 39.20736, 
   85.3836, 185.975252, 405.095196, 882.399269, 1922.095421, 
   4186.829292, 9120.018288};
b0 [j_] := b00[[j]];
a0 [j_] := a00[[j]];

Psi[r_, z_, j_] := Exp[-b0[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a0[j]*r^2];
nmax = Dimensions[b00][[1]];

Kk[r_, z_, j1_, j2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z, j2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, z, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]*r*2*Pi];
Kx[j1_, j2_] := -(1/2)*
   NIntegrate[
    Kk[r, z, j1, j2], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Kxx = Table[Kx[j1, j2], {j1, 1, nmax}, {j2, 1, nmax}];

Ka[r_, z_, j1_, j2_] := 
  FullSimplify[Psi[r, z, j2]*1/2*r^2*Psi[r, z, j1]*r*2*Pi];
KA[j1_, j2_] := 
  KA[j1, j2] = 
   KA[j2, j1] = 
    NIntegrate[
     Ka[r, z, j1, j2], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
KAx = Table[KA[j1, j2], {j1, 1, nmax}, {j2, 1, nmax}];

Ks[r_, z_, j1_, j2_] := 
  FullSimplify[Psi[r, z, j2]*(-1)*Psi[r, z, j1]*r*2*Pi];
KS[j1_, j2_] := 
  KS[j1, j2] = 
   KS[j2, j1] = 
    NIntegrate[
     Ks[r, z, j1, j2], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
KSx = Table[KS[j1, j2], {j1, 1, nmax}, {j2, 1, nmax}];

VP1[r_, z_] := -(1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]);
Px1[j1_, j2_] := 
  Px1[j1, j2] = 
   Px1[j2, j1] = 
    NIntegrate[
     Psi[r, z, j2]*VP1[r, z]*Psi[r, z, j1]*r*2*Pi, {r, 0, 
      Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Pxx1 = Table[Px1[j1, j2], {j1, 1, nmax}, {j2, 1, nmax}];

Bb[j1_, j2_] := 
  Bb[j1, j2] = 
   Bb[j2, j1] = 
    NIntegrate[
     Psi[r, z, j2]*Psi[r, z, j1]*r*2*Pi, {r, 0, 
      Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Bxx = Table[Bb[j1, j2], {j1, 1, nmax}, {j2, 1, nmax}];

EEE = Kxx + Pxx1 + KAx + KSx;
Sort[Eigenvalues[{EEE, Bxx}]](*Energies*)


Out[88]= {-1.02221, -0.173374, -0.0199577, 0.312572, 1.18162,
2.72596, 5.63718, 12.0333, 17.9735, 28.2709, 61.4758, 135.447,
298.338, 656.001, 1440.89, 3168.65, 7007.42, 15772.6, 37523.6}
```

Comment: The functions you are using don't look even remotely orthogonal, so what stops you from interpolating more of them with intermittent parameters between the ones you have? In the limit of a continuous two-parameter set you end up with something like a wavelet transform as far as I can see. If your solver algorithm is robust, it should be able to give you good solutions.

Comment: @FlatterMann, thanks for the comment! Using the intermittent parameters, you mean to take additional parameters inside each segment? For instance for $a0j$ to take parameter between 0.500074 (the 1st element) and 0.502676 (the 2nd element), next parameter between 0.502676  (the 3rd element) and 0.510451 (the 4th element), etc?

Comment: @FlatterMann, could you please write about the wavelet transform in more detail? if it's not difficult for you could you please show how to do it in the case of my basis?

Comment: Are you sure for the notation in cylindrical coordinates ?  Are these $\left(\rho,\phi,z\right)$ and not $\left(r,\phi,z\right)$ as you post ? Reference [Unit vectors in the cylindrical coordinate system as functions of position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422163/).

Comment: @Frobenius, thanks! I have changed

Comment: Where did those parameter values come from?

Comment: @Ghoster, from the supplementary materials of this article https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/147/24/244108/195534/Accurate-and-balanced-anisotropic-Gaussian-type (I have considered the case of 1s state with B=2). The values of the excited states from another article

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Your b coefficients are more or less just a power series (powers of two) and so are part of your a coefficients. I don't see anything special about the choice of these functions over any other, except maybe that you have been (over?) fitting them to the known solution of the ground state?

Comment: @FlatterMann, thanks for the comment! Yes, you are absolutely right, these functions have been fitted to the known exact solution of the ground state

Comment: @FlatterMann, I have just check your advice with the intermittent parameters, work not correct, Wolfram Mathematica gives the next unrealistic values: -3089.11, -618.943, -113.15, -16.9449, -5.26332, **-1.02221**, **-0.173762**,
**-0.0550228**, 0.0846537, 0.340474 ... Among eigenvalues there are functions from previous basis set (highlighted in bold)

Comment: @FlatterMann, could you please demonstrate the wavelet transform method for this task

Comment: You can always use the [Graham-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) procedure to generate an orthonormal basis from a set of linearly dependent vectors.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the advice! I am new to this, so if it's not difficult for you, I would be glad if you could demonstrate it.

Comment: @Andrew The problem here does not seem to be orthonormality but completeness. This looks like a fairly random set of functions that was probably chosen by someone to give a reasonably good representation of the ground state. They clearly can not represent the excited states very well.

Comment: @FlatterMann Right, but if you can generate $N$ linearly independent vectors, then by Graham Schmidt you can turn that into a orthonormal basis that is complete on an $N$ dimensional space. So the issues are related. Of course, you aren't guaranteed that the space that your basis spans is particularly meaningful if you just pick random vectors to start with.

Comment: @Andrew This is an infinite dimensional problem. Trying to represent a subset of its solutions with a finite number of base functions is doomed to fail unless one is really, really careful. I am not aware of a simple method to "guess" a good base. If there is (other than variational methods to determine the ground state, if I remember correctly), then we don't seem to teach it at the undergrad level. My observation was simply a hint for the OP about what seems to be going wrong. I don't believe orthogonalization alone can fix the problem.