# Extension of a Spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

If a spring of spring constant $k$ and very small mass  is stretched by a force $F_L$ on the left and a force $F_R$ on its right, with $F_L > F_R$, by how much does the spring extend?

If the forces were equal, the spring would extend by $\Delta x = F/k$, but not sure how to deal with different amounts of forces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123409/extension-of-an-unfixed-spring